# How were "catalog" picture files created?

Tags: graphics, identify-this-software

Back in the 1990s there were CD-ROMs containing a large collection of pictures split across several folders, where each folder would have a "catalog" file at the top. This file was basically a picture containing thumbnails of everything inside the folder, with a file name underneath each thumbnail.

Here is an example [[source](http://cd.textfiles.com/gifsgalore/GIFS/PEOPLE/)]:

[image: 002CAT.GIF]

How were these "catalog" files created? In other words what program created the picture above?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could have whipped something like that up in Turbo C/C++ pretty quickly. Scan the directory and add the scaled bitmap and file name in a particular grid.

Comment: There's a folder full of viewers. Probably one of them. http://cd.textfiles.com/gifsgalore/VIEWERS/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the program, it's called **Graphics Display System** or **GDS** for short, version 2 specifically.

Looking into the metadata of the catalog picture, I stumbled on this tag: `Profile-gif:gdscatalog2`
So I went searching in the parent directories for anything starting with 'gds' and found a program called 'Graphics Display System'. After acquiring and testing several versions of it I determined that version 2 produced the exact same result as the catalog picture I have.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

It could well have been [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick), which has been around since 1987, is free, and can do this kind of thing: I've used it for batch production of thumbnails.

Taking a look at the metadata of these images might provide clues.

Comment: Though chances of commercial producers of CD-ROMs using ImageMagick instead of something in-house are pretty slim.

Comment: I worked for a CD-ROM publisher in 1987-88. They were pretty low-budget operations, and concentrated their software efforts on stuff they could not source externally.

Comment: The metadata did have a clue and I found the program, thank you for the hint! ImageMagick looks interesting though so I'll give it a try.

Comment: I doubt ImageMagick would use this font (it’s not a popular one), and I doubt it would put a resolution next to some, but not all images.

Answer (score -1):

I did this kind of catalogs for my mp3 CD's simply with Thumbs Plus for batch resizing of the covers and assembled them simply with MS-Paint. I created a new empty picture of the right amount of pixels to be able to print it in 300dpi. I used the batch resize function of Thumbs Plus to resize all images to the right size and then would simply copy/paste each image in that empty image. Save and voilà. Catalog cover in the right size for a a CD jewel case in 5 minutes.

You can also use the [Thumbs Plus](http://www.cerious.com/) program directly to make such catalogs.
PS: I have no link to that program, I only use it since I have a PC (1995).